# click command won't work on combobox?

Tags: selenium, combobox, click

I'm trying to click an item in a `combobox`. That item is supposed to load a new page.  But the browser only chooses the item without opening a new page.  This is the snippet:

```
package org.example.tests;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class TestQuickLinks {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl="http://www.stts.edu";
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(baseUrl);
    }

    @Test
    public void testQuickLinks() throws Exception {
        driver.findElement(By.id("link")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//option[@value='Organisasi']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        try {
            assertEquals("Organisasi STTS - Tentang STTS - Sekolah Tinggi Teknik Surabaya", driver.getTitle());
        } catch (Error e) {
            verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "this is not the correct page");
        }
    }
}
```

I tried clicking on the item manually and it works fine.
I also tried using the same code on a dummy page and it works fine.  Can anyone help me?
I tried asking on the mIRC but they're ignoring me....

Comment: When you ask questions that involve a specific behavior, you should post the HTML of the page as well.

Comment: the HTML of the page consists a large javascript and I don't know which part of it handles the behavior I'm looking for... the snippet has a baseUrl of the website though...

Comment: Can you please mention the name of combo in the page? Only your selenium webdriver code is not enough to understand details. Can you please describe the steps manually what you clicked?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you not to use byXpath method, Instead try using By.linkText if its a link or you may also use By.id/By.name.

Comment: the element only has the "value" attribute. and it's linkText also exists in a different part of the page so I can't use linkText or name.. I wanted to use the "value" attribute but Selenium 2 doesn't seem to have that kind of identifier...

Answer (score 0):

Use your SelectElement class.  I'm not sure exactly how this works in Java but here is the C# method:

```
public class TestQuickLinks {
    private WebDriver driver;
    private String baseUrl="http://www.stts.edu";
    private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(baseUrl);
    }

    @Test
    public void testQuickLinks() throws Exception {
        WebElement thisElement =driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("select[id='link']"));
        SelectElement select = new SelectElement(thisElement);
        select.SelectByIndex(3); //sets the combo box or select box to the desired value
        thisElement.Click(); //this is needed to activate the sites javascript onChange event.
    }
```